# Margins in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about the grid system in Bootstrap. I seems to work great, but there are no margins between the "boxes". for example if I have this:

```
<div class="column">

  <div class="span11"> 

  </div>

  <div class="span11">

  </div>

</div>
```

This works great. But there is no space between then. So do I assign an "id" and edit it myself though CSS code? Is this the right way to do it? for example:

```
<div class="column">

  <div id="box_1" class="span11"> 

  </div>

  <div id="box_2" class="span11">

  </div>

</div>
```

and one more thing, as for borders, colors, do I do the same ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there's no .column in twitter bootstrap but .row

If you want left/right margin use a span10 with offset1

If you want top/bottom margin creat a new .row and apply a class like .show-grid

For borders and colors use classes for generic and ids for specific.

You can create your mockup on jsFiddle like this http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/EHutn/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.show-grid {
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.show-grid [class*="span"] {
background-color: #EEEEEE;
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
line-height: 30px;
min-height: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row show-grid">
<div class="span10 offset1"> 
<p>bla bla bla</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row show-grid">
<div class="span10 offset1">
<p>bla bla bla</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```